# Adding new types to compiled code (treating it like data)

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

This question is strictly about the inefficient architecture of an existing system that needs to be rebuilt. It solicits validation from fellow developers who have had experience with managing such awkward systems. I have tried to abstract it as best as I could below.

The application caters to a very complex need and it delivers very well. The problem is that internal plumbing makes code management and scalability a nightmare. The little information I can share about context includes the fact that we need to treat code as a data commodity. In other words, the system can only function if implemented classes are added to it on a continuing basis.

What the application delivers to end-users is not data, but an `[Action]` that requires a code execution context. So the application has to execute some code on the target system in order to deliver what the user expects. Now these expectations are not known at compile-time and new ones need to be added almost on a daily basis. That means, developers keep adding `[Actions]` to the system regularly.

The existing system links to these `[Action]` classes statically! Not only does that make code management a nightmare, but also requires a recompile every time an action is added.

My first instinct was to have the system dynamically link to assemblies at runtime where each assembly would contain a bunch of actions. This would be akin to adding extensibility capabilities to the application. I thought about the MEF framework but it just did not feel right.

The only alternative I can think of is storing each action in the database as either source code or a compiled module. Each has its own trade-offs such as storing as source is less secure but gives me more control over code review and continued maintenance. Storing as compiled has the benefit of server-side assembly signing.

I would appreciate some advice about how to structure a system like this.

Comment: Another option would be to use the dlr, so could write the "action" in say ruby or python. Lots of fun stuff like building on the fly, caching. Reflection.Emit without all the scaffolding

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: I thought about that but am uncomfortable with client-side compilation. Whether we store as source or compiled, the client will always get a compiled version.

Comment: If you were to put assemblies in the db that would be client side compilation as well as would picking them up through a URL, or doing some sort of AutoUpdate mechanism so I'm not seeing where the discomfort is coming from.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: The discomfort comes from the fact that with server compilation, we can have server-side strong-signed assemblies. Yes it would still mean client-side dynamic linking but not without validation.

Comment: Um, deploy them with a certificate would take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a more flexible architecture, but a more flexible software process. Adding new functionality on a daily basis is what most developers do. That doesn't a valid argument for a plugin system.

You don't need a plugin architecture. You need a good software development methodology, such as the agile processes (such as Scrum and XP), and make sure you be able to do this:

- Let developers build new components in braches.
- After thorough testing, merge new functionality to the main branch.
- This way the main branch always has production quality and you can roll out new versions each day using continuous integration and continuous delivery.

Comment: I may have not explained the context properly enough. Consider a SaaS software that you subscribe to. It allows you to download a desktop app. You request a new functionality from the service and when it is available, the app automatically downloads it and `[executes]` it. It's like an on-demand executable delivery platform.

Comment: This is very different from adding `[features]` to an existing app. This app has NO functionality except to deliver executable payloads to the user machine.